# Is there a name for these long, snaky paint drips?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

If you smear paint on a wall, the combination of surface-tension and viscosity makes it trickle down in little “stalagtites” of paint instead of all at once:

[image]

Do these little “stalagtites” of paint have a name?

I would like to distinguish them from, say, the drops of paint which drip from a painted ceiling, and have detached entirely from the mother smear.

Comment: I would add that the word you're looking for as a simile is *stalactite* (and the opposing formation is a *stalagmite*).

Comment: This image is from [Canstock](http://www.canstockphoto.com/paint-dripping-8825955.html). I don't believe their licence terms allow this use, given that SE has a CC-BY-SA licence. A picture is good, but please find one which can be used here [and ensure it's referenced correctly!]

Comment: I've heard older painters call these "holidays." When junior painters did a poor job it was an insult implying they weren't paying attention to their work because they were "on holiday."

Comment: If it was wine on a wine glass they'd be called *legs* :)

Comment: Sometimes newcomer answers can be enlightening, but I wish they would explain their answers, otherwise "older" users might believe they are time wasters. Tim's comment also proved to be very helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> [*If you accidentally repaint a car too quickly, without proper flash times, huge **paint sags** and runs can flow down and ruin the finish, especially on vertical panels.*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=d6LvAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA905&dq=%22paint%20sags%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22paint%20sags%22&f=false)
>
> (thefreedictionary.com)
> [**sag**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sagging) noun 2a. *A sagging or drooping part or area: **tried to brush out the paint sags.***

They're also often called *paint **runs***.

Comment: I'd say there are some *sags* at the top of the picture but the dominant feature is the *runs* where the paint makes a break for it and forms a long thin "stalactite". These are common in both sprayed and brushed oil- and water-based paints. When brushed, water-based paints tend not to go on thick enough/surface-dry fast enough for sags to form.

Comment: @Chris: Personally, if I was going to distinguish *sags* from *runs*, I think probably *I'd say there are some sags at the **bottom** of the picture*. That's because I tend to think of the raised bobbly bits as the "essence" of what we're talking about. Which is usually thought of as something highly undesirable (rather than "artistic"), so as a painter your problem is you need to sand the surface to level it. And the "sag" at the bottom of each "run" is the most awkward bit to sand down because it's thick, meaning you have to wait ages for it to be fully dried and "sandable".

Comment: There are sags at the ends of the runs as well, that's true.

Comment: @Chris: There may be a US/UK split, and almost certainly there's a usage split between *artistic* painters (for whom this effect may actually be useful), and those in the painting & decorating trade (for whom it's just a sign of incompetence). I've heard many of the latter use *sags, sagging* in reference to the whole thing, not just the bobbly bits themselves.

Comment: A paint sag is something different from what the OP pictures.  A paint sag occurs when an entire (vertical) surface has been painted and some of the paint slides down and merges with paint below, forming a bulge in the fully-painted surface.  (And it's not simply a sign of "incompetence", as there are many disparate factors that combine to determine how well paint will stay in place once applied.)

Comment: @Hot Licks: For a usage like this, different people will have different opinions about what exactly (if any) difference there is between, say, *sags, runs,* and [*curtains*](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120902063908AAnol4Z). The way your comment is worded implies some kind of "objective, absolute" set of definitions that all Anglophones would naturally agree on (or be persuaded into accepting, on the basis of some particularly authoritative dictionary). I trust you agree that at the end of the day, such distinctions are really just personal perspectives/matters of opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yeah, but my opinion trumps everyone else's.

Comment: @Hot Licks: And an exceptionally good opinion it is! But like it or lump it, we do have a lot of nns here who sometimes seem to think all Anglophones (except maybe the "uneducated" ones) agree on the precise scope of each word. And that if there *are* any disagreements, whatever <insert favourite dictionary or ELU user here> says is *the* correct semantic distinction. Things just ain't that precise.

Answer (score 11):

In the graffiti culture they are just called ***drips***, and are often used intentionally for artistic effect.

> ***Drips*** - At first drips are the sign of a novice painter who
>   does not have good can control. Over time a writer can get so good
>   that he or she intentionally drips their tags in order to show
>   style....This style originated early on in New York subway graffiti
>   with home made markers ([here](http://www.snakeoilmagazine.com/pages/terms.html))

Comment: +1 This term is used outside the graffiti culture as well, although more conventional painters usually avoid these drips, and regard them as a sign that the paint was applied too heavily. I remember a commercial from a long time ago where the Hall of Fame baseball catcher Johnny Bench did an ad for a brand of spray paint, touting its ability to spray on evenly. The clever tagline was, "No runs, no drips, no errors," which of course was a pun of sorts derived from, "No runs, no hits, no errors," a phrase commonly used by television announcers at the end of a half inning of baseball.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday, a newcomer named Pen posted the following answer:

> *We grew up calling them 'holidays'*.

The answer has since been deleted. It seemed an odd answer, but it didn't sound offensive or gratuitous to me. So, I looked online and found the following definitions:

> [Painting and Coatings Terms and Definitions](http://www.thepaintersexpress.com/paint_coatings_glossary.html)
>
> **Holidays**: Application defect whereby small areas are left uncoated. Synonyms: *Misses*, *Skips*, *Voids*, *Discontinuities*, *Vacations*.

and from *[Coating Defects-Common Coating Failures and Causes](http://www.capital-painting.com/coating-defects/)*

> - Coating Defects: ***Runs***, ***Sags***, ***Curtains***, ***Wrinkles***
>   [image]
>   *Runs*, *sags*, *curtains*, or *wrinkles* may be caused or worsened by: applying the coating too thickly, using too much thinner or using the wrong thinner, surface too hot to apply the coating, applying a coating at the end of its pot life, wrong thixotrope used in manufacturing , improper spray technique.
> - Discontinuities: ***Skips***, ***Holidays***, and ***Missed Areas***
>   These defects are exposed areas of the substrate or previous coating, caused by poor application technique, lack of stripe coating, and/or lack of or poor inspection. Quick recognition and repair means the repair is easier and it will blend in better.

If the drips or ‘sags’ are large then the term **[curtains](http://www.sharpe1.com/sharpe/sharpe.nsf/Page/Paint+Terminology)**, used in the painting industry, is also appropriate.

> **Curtains**
> Large sagging or runs of paint due to improper application.

Comment: The picture in the Original Poster's question doesn't seem to mean **Application defect whereby small areas are left uncoated**. Can it be even called **defect**?

Comment: @Rathony I'm sick of your bold type abuse. It really comes across as **patronising**. If you haven't understood why I posted this answer, I'm not going to waste my time to explain it to you.

Comment: Holiday was **deleted** by commmunity votes. I don't think it is synonymous with sags or drips. I am sick of your editing worthless questions and correcting. How about that?

Comment: @Rathony and I am sick of seeing you protect every question when answers from newcomers  are not spam, offensive or saying "me too" or "thanks". How about that?

Comment: That's my right at 15,000 reputation points. I have the right to make important words bold as much as you have the right to save the blatantly off-topic and ELL question. You are the one who complained about the low quality questions. Why are you helping learners? I am very curious to know your true intention. Will it be really **helpful to current and future users?** If you have a problem with my protecting all those questions answered by one rep users, please write a Meta post. As far as I am concerned, nobody, no moderator told me I should stop it.

Comment: @Rathony  I believe I am quite coherent, see my reply on meta to a question of yours http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/7525/44619 You can edit your question if you want to bring up the issue on meta.

Comment: That's your opinion. Not a consensus or guideline. I firmly believe that all the questions should be auto-protected after a few to 7 days. If a newbie wants to answer any protected question, they can earn 10 easily and come back. I see more benefits than harm from protecting those questions. Now, when did you learn how to say "ridurre, decrescere, diminuire" in Italian? If a learner who doesn't know the antonym of to quicken or synonym of to slow or slow down, they don't belong here. They belong on ELL. Trying to reopen the question doesn't help the OP. If you want to help, guide him to ELL.

Comment: where they will be welcome and upvoted. They will be downvoted and closevoted on ELU. Your edit doesn't improve the question and it makes it look more like a thesaurus question. Our community should have closed the question a minute after it was posted with this comment, [Look at the thesaurus. You belong on ELL](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/quicken). Don't you agree?

Comment: fair enough observation about ELL, but the answers that question generated were quite good and valid, and it was useful (or interesting) for 2047 visitors! There were suggestions that didn't occur to me, and who knows there may be someone in the future who could add another legitimate and reasonable suggestion. And, yes, you're absolutely right that is my personal opinion.

Comment: If you look at the link, how many questions do you think I can ask on ELU if we allow that kind of question? What is the antonym of decelerate? What is the synonym of hasten? What is the antonym of slow? Those questions are considered off-topic on ELL. Let's not welcome it. Let's close it and guide those poor learners who don't know the difference between ELU and ELL to ELL where they belong.